# React Native Expo Network Request Failed HTTPS

Tags: react-native, error-handling, https, expo

I am currently working on an app that has a seperate fronend and a backend.

Backend is spring boot which accepts only HTTPS with a self signed ceritificate.
Frontend is and React Native App with Expo.

Currently, I can't send HTTPS requests through the frontend. When I do, it gives me the following error:

```
Network request failed
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:null in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I renewed my self signed certificate as I read online that might be causing issues. These are the scripts in packagejson:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
```

The code I am sending the request could be found here:

```
login = () => {
        const data = { email: email, password: password};
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
        };
        console.log(data);
        fetch(`https://192.xxxx:8443/login?email=${encodeURIComponent(data.email)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(data.password)}`, )
        .then((reponse) => reponse.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };
```

where xxxx is the IP address found from the command prompt. I have no idea what is causing this issue. The requests are not arriving to the frontend but when I use postman, they work fine. I dont know whether I have to include the crt file in the frontend and change configs, or just create a new one for frontend just so both are secure and can communicate.

Can anybody help me with the error and the logic a bit?

- Renewed the certificate
- Converted to Ipv4

Answer (score 0):

The issue was IOS couldnt locate localhost. Neither IP worked. I used ngrok to host the local host online. This way network error was fixed.